# How to pass powershell hashtable from one script to another script in Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: powershell, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

In the local system I am able to execute powershell script by passing hashtable but the same is not working in Jenkins pipeline . I tried in Multiple ways but none of them working. Could you please help me on this.

I need solutions for couple of things

1. How can I pass a powershell hashtable to a groovy command
2. If above can't work how can I execute powershell script from powershell script block

   ```
    stage('Passing Hashtable Test')
            {
                steps{


                    script{
                            powershell '''

                            write-host "hello Passing Hashtable "

                            $dict = @{ 
                            "firstKey" = "abc";
                            "User" = "Robot"
                            }

                            Write-host "Keys are present here : " + $dict.Keys   

                            $env:WORKSPACE\PassingDictonary.ps1 -param1 "ThisIsStringValuePassed" -myHashTable $dict     

                            '''
                             echo "priting outside script1 $dict"  //how to get Powershell $dict variable here ?

              //Atleast If I can send hashtable to ps1 file then its good  . I tried this but not working


          //OR At least If I can get Powershell variable outside of the block .. so that I would like to use a bat command by using -file parameter but I am not able to get value here.




                }
            }
        }
   ```

This is my PassingDictionary.ps1 file code  (this is working locally)

```
param (

    [string]$param1 = "something",
    [hashtable]$myHashTable
)


Write-host "Param1 value is : " + $param1

write-host "length of my Passed Hashtable is :" + $myHashTable.Count


foreach($k in $myHashTable.Keys)
{

    Write-Host "Prining myHashTable Key is : => " + $k

    Write-Host "Prining myHashTable Value  is : => " + $myHashTable[$k]


}
```

Comment: Typo. Should be `$dict =`

Comment: Sorry @zett42 I did not get  where do I need to use $dict? Could you please let me know more details

Comment: Write dict as json inside PowerShell and parse json in Jenkins.

Comment: In the Groovy file. Line `dict = @{` is missing $.

Comment: Sorry i edited the code with dollar but still it s not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last I am able to execute powershell script from powershell block in Jenkins pipeline like below (this gives solution for my 2nd problem which mentioned above )

```
script {

   powershell ''' 
   PowerShell(. '.\\PassingDictonary.ps1' -param1 "ThisIsStringValuePassed"     
      -myHashTable $dict) 

    ''' 
 }
```